# Not able to delete directory from Azure Storage container by Databricks notebook

Tags: azure, shell, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to delete empty directories from Azure storage container which mounted to my DBFS

I'm able to list all directories which has no files.

```
%sh
find /dbfs/mnt/test/logs/2021 -empty -type d
```

Result :

```
/dbfs/mnt/test/logs/2021/02/12
/dbfs/mnt/test/logs/2021/02/15
/dbfs/mnt/test/logs/2021/02/16
```

But when I try to delete them, it is failing with Resource temporary unavailable.

```
%sh
find /dbfs/mnt/test/logs/ -type d -exec rmdir {} \;
```

Result:

```
rmdir: failed to remove '/dbfs/mnt/test/logs/': Directory not empty
rmdir: failed to remove '/dbfs/mnt/test/logs/2021': Directory not empty
rmdir: failed to remove '/dbfs/mnt/test/logs/2021/02': Directory not empty
rmdir: failed to remove '/dbfs/mnt/test/logs/2021/02/12': Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I'm able to successfully remove files older than certain days.. removing direcotry is not working. (Below command to remove files working

```
%sh
find /dbfs/mnt/test/logs/ -name "*.log" -type f -mtime +5 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing to remember - DBFS is an abstraction over the cloud blob storage, where there is no real directories - they are just prefixes that are used to organize data.  And if you do `%sh ls -ls /dbfs/mnt/test/logs/` you may notice that all directories will have the same timestamp, and it could be the recent one  - I don't remember out the head how it's calculated.  Only files have the timestamp.

So if you need to reliably remove directories, it's better to use  `dbutils.fs.rm('/mnt/test/logs/', True)` (in Python, or similar in the Scala) to remove directory recursively (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#dbutils-fs)). But there are limitations, like there is no support for wildcards, etc., so you need to generate a list of directories to delete, and do the deletion.

Comment: yeah I was using this before. was really looking if it was possible to use shell commands.. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: In my case, using ```dbutils.fs.rm("path", True)``` is giving an error: ```shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: hadoop_azure_shaded.com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: This operation is not permitted on a non-empty directory.```

Comment: I am unable to using dbutils.fs.rm in a notebook with the same error even with recursive set to true in python.